# 画像から画像の一部を見つける

Tags: java, 画像

完全一致でいいのですが、Javaで画像から画像の一部を検索するライブラリかメソッドなどはありますか？

例えば、

- PCのスクリーン全体のスクリーンショット … A画像
- ウィンドウの閉じるボタンの画像 … B画像

A画像の中からB画像を検索（完全一致でもいい）してB画像の検出されたA画像上の座標を取得したいです。

画像は `java.awt.Image` です

Answer (score 7, accepted):

コンピュータ・ビジョン(Computer Vision)向けの[OpenCVライブラリ](http://opencv.org/)に、テンプレート・マッチング(Template Matching)という機能があり、対象画像の中に画像が一致する場所があるか？を調べられます。厳密一致だけではなく、ある程度似ている画像（相関度）も探すことができます。

- http://opencv.blog.jp/java/template_matching
- http://workpiles.com/2015/05/opencv-matchtemplate-java/

Comment: ありがとうございます！
やはりあるものですね！